# Install *IPFS* to a blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, ipfs

I just want to install IPFS to a blob storage. Means all the files I will upload will point to that azure blob storage not my localhost. Is that possible ?

Comment: Does Azure Blob Storage have native IPFS support?

Comment: you can use [Azure File Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) not sure if it is an option for you ?